# mod_rewrite not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new to working with .htaccess and I'm having trouble using `mod_rewrite` for apache.

So basically I have a URL.    `www.website.com/test/index.php`

and I'd like it to be shorter `www.website.com/t/index.php`

So in my `.htaccess` file I have these three lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) t/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works perfectly for directing me to www.website.com/t/index.php but the index.php page wont load and will only display a `404 error`. Any help would be greatly apprectiated.

Comment: Please consider posting this on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: How do you know the rewrite works if you are getting a 404 error?

Comment: Well when I go to www.website.com/test/index.php it re-directs me to www.website.com/t/index.php but the index.php wont load with the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the shortening of your URL first:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/(.*) t/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...and then make sure, the new (and nonexisting) URL will get processed:

```
RewriteRule ^t/(.*) test/$1 [L]
```

The first rewrite is "external", so it is displayed in client browser address bar, but the second is "internal", so apache only displays results from the new URL in place of the old one w/o any change in clients address bar.